# No recording indicator in control center when microphone is in use

Tags: audio, privacy, microphone

According to the [macOS User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-the-microphone-on-mac-mchla1b1e1fe/mac):

> The Recording Indicator light in Control Center shows you when your computer’s microphone is in use or has been used recently... The light turns on when you open the Sound Input pane in Sound System Preferences.

But I don't see any kind of recording indicator:

[image]

I've tested with a variety of apps, including by creating an audio recording in QuickTime Player:

[image]

What gives?

Comment: Either System Preferences is exempt, or because it's only showing the level, not triggering it. Try using QuickTime audio recording to test it.

Comment: @Ezekiel I've tested it with a variety of apps. What gets me is the part that says "The light turns on when you open the Sound Input pane in Sound System Preferences."

Comment: I can confirm it should appear when you have that QT window open, so definitely odd. Can you confirm your OS version?

Comment: @Ezekiel It's Big Sur because Control Center says ‘Do Not Disturb’ not ‘Focus’.

Comment: @grg ah, good catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new feature in macOS 12 Monterey and is not present in macOS 11 Big Sur.

> #### Privacy
>
> **Recording indicator**
> See which apps have access to the mic on your Mac in Control Centre. A new software indicator augments the camera indicator light by showing you whenever an app has access to your mic.

https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey/features/